# math: what font can be seen in the picture?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

In what font is the letter written?

[image]

Comment: Try `\mathfrak{i}`

Comment: @DG' You beat me by 10 seconds :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano -- 

Comment: To be more concise: The font is probably called Euler Fraktur which is loaded by the `amssymb` package (which provides the above mentioned `\mathfrak` command).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{i}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a terminology kn the mathematics community when to use mathfrak?

Comment: @Simon Yes in Abstract Algebra for the Ideals for example.